# C# Always retry tcp connection if connection failed

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

below is my code to start tcp connection for my clients to server:

```
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
```

ConnectCallback:

```
    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Info(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But my code only do connection once while my system starts. How do we do retry connect if the first time attempts fails?

And always will do retry if connection always fails?

And maybe do retry every 30 seconds?

Comment: Start another async call from ConnectCallback in case of failure. Pass along the number of failed attempts if you want to set a max.

Comment: Is switching to TPL (async/await Task) an option?

Comment: Fildor, How do we check whether or not the connection is failed?

Comment: "SocketException
An error occurred when attempting to access the socket." - [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I'd not catch `Exception` anyway. You want to catch `SocketException` because that is the one you can and want to handle. Let the others bubble up to your global exception handler.

Comment: Fildor, the exception will be coming out from which line?

Comment: See my answer. It should be thrown on EndConnect.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
```

If you want to keep track of failed attempts and want to keep the good ol' async pattern, I'd pass a state object:

```
class ConnectionState {
    Socket Client {get; set;}
    int FailedAttempts {get; set;} = 0;
}
```

Then pass that:

```
client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), new ConnectionState(){ .Client = client, FailedAttempts = 0});
```

In the Callback:

```
private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ConnectionState state = (ConnectionState)ar.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        state.Client.EndConnect(ar);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        _logger.Info(ex.ToString());
        if( state.FailedAttempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS )
        {
            state.FailedAttempts += 1;
            state.Client.BeginConnect( remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), state );

            // you may also check the exception for what happened exactly.
            // There may be conditions where retrying does not make sense.
            // See SocketException.ErrorCode
        }
        else
        {
            // You may want to handle exceeding max tries.
            // - Notify User
            // - Maybe throw a custom exception
        }
    }
}
```

Reference for SocketException ErrorCodes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2

For setting up a time-based retry mechanism, I'd create some kind of "connection watchdog": Have a timer check client field every X seconds. If it is null and a connection-startup-attempt is not running already, start one.

---

Personally, I'd try and switch to [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), though. But I consider that as an alternative and not a direct answer to your question. But I recommend it.

Comment: what's TPL may I ask?

Comment: What if I want it to retry forever? No need max attempts

Comment: I added a link to the answer. But if you do not know what it is, reading up on it may take you quite some time.

Comment: _"What if I want it to retry forever?"_ Then just BeginConnect without the check, _but_ I would _always_ give the user the possibility to cancel trying. So maybe have it check some boolean ShouldRetryConnection (or something alike).

Comment: What to do if I want to retry every 30 sec or 1 min?

Comment: You can "inject" a little async waiting by starting a custom async function that simply does Thread.Sleep() and then starts the actual async function in its callback. Or, have a timer check if 1) connection has been established and 2) a connect request is running. If both are false, starts a new connect attempt. That would also give you an automated "reconnect".